# NPM: don't install if parent directory's node_modules satisfies dependency

Tags: npm, dependencies

In an effort to save space, I've installed large packages in a common parent directory to all my projects. The scripts in these projects can refer to modules in this parent directory (see this in [Node's documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders)), yet `npm install`-ing in a freshly-cloned project pulls *everything*, not just the ones that the project needs on top of the ones inherited from the common parent. **Are there any options to make `npm install` download only what it needs to?**

Minimal example: consider the below file structure.

```
├ projects
│   ├ package.json <- specifies a dependency on `some_module^1.0.0`
│   ├ node_modules
│   │   └ some_module
│   │       └ ...
│   └ some_project
│       └ package.json <- also specifies a dependency on `some_module^1.0.0`
```

If `npm install` is run in `projects/some_project`, it will download `some_module` unconditionally.

(Note: this is not related to `npm dedupe` and the module duplication it solves, because this is solely a directory hierarchy: the parent directory project doesn't depend on any of the subfolders.)

Comment: I too would like an answer to this problem. If you `require()` something and node's [name resolution](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) can find things in the parent directory, then why when installing would it install a duplicate locally?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue. I am in the same situation at the moment

Comment: @almcaffee sadly no, I've just given up and let it be, periodically clearing big node_modules from seldom-used projects.